# How to add search Option in Street view Map i Google map plugin

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

i used google map plugin in my application. For Street view map there is no search option in that plugin . But my application requires search option in street view map. I used the following code for street view map.

​

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=ABQIAAAAuPsJpk3MBtDpJ4G8cqBnjRRaGTYH6UMl8mADNa0YKuWNNa8VNxQCzVBXTx2DYyXGsTOxpWhvIG7Djw" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var myPano;

function initialize() {
  var fenwayPark = new GLatLng(42.345573,-71.098326);
  panoramaOptions = { latlng:fenwayPark };
  myPano = new GStreetviewPanorama(document.getElementById("pano"), panoramaOptions);
  GEvent.addListener(myPano, "error", handleNoFlash);
}

function handleNoFlash(errorCode) {
  if (errorCode == FLASH_UNAVAILABLE) {
    alert("Error: Flash doesn't appear to be supported by your browser");
    return;
  }
}  

</script>
```

How can i add search option in that street view map? Help me out in this issue..

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "search option"? A search bar that is on top of the Street View image? What will it do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a search function you should have a value that will receive the value of what you want to search. So probably an address, so this address should be Geocoded on the postback by a button